# Apache Django webpage is not saving values for long period of time

Tags: django, apache, webserver

I have setup my Django server with Apache. In my Django view's function am using Global variable to pass values from one function to another.As I have to use same value in second function as well.

So when I call function F1 it gives output on Page-1 and after clicking button passing same value to Page-2 but if I wait for 5-10 sec on Page-1 then it shows nothing on Page-2.I don't know why?

As the same function is carrying values fine with Django builtin web but not with Apache.Can anyone help me on this issue??

Is issue related to Apache or Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do that. Constants are ok, but global variables cannot guarantee consistency across threads. Not that you cannot do this, but you need to be very careful and know what you are doing.

For this functionality, use [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) variables or the [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/) instead.

Comment: Thanks alot bro you saved me as issue get resolved with session method.